# AngularJS : Reuse custom directive programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I am working on my first single page Angular.js application and am kind of stuck at programmatically compilling/evaluating a custom directive in order to insert it into the DOM from within a controller. The custom directive I created uses two values (which return functions and take a parameter) and a parameter. The whole thing works fine with ng-repeat in the initial html of the SPA:

```
.directive('myDirective', ['value1', 'value2', function('value1', 'value2'){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            param: '=param'
        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.v1 = value1(scope.param);
            scope.v2 = value2(scope.param);
        }
    };
})
```

The directive template looks somewhat like this:

```
<div>
    <img ng-src="{{ param.img.src }}" />
    <div>
        <a href="{{ param.link.src }}">{{ param.link.text }}</a>
        <time datetime="{{ v1 }}">{{ v2 | date: 'medium' }}</time>
        <span ng-bind-html="param.text | customFilter1 | customFilter2 | customFilter3"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works out nicely when I use this directive in the page html like this:

```
<ul ng-controller="SomeController" ng-cloak>
    <li ng-repeat="param in params">
        <my-directive param="param"></my-directive>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I now would like to reuse the directive to dynamically generate the respective html programmatically in a function from within a controller.
My approach thereto tried to use the `$compile` function but without success:

```
// in controller:
// ...
$scope.generateMyDirective = function(param){
    var compiled = $compile('<my-directive param="param"></my-directive>')({});
    someElement.innerHTML = compiled[0];
};
```

The result (i.e. `someElement`) does include the static html of the directive, but won't evaluate any expressions within the directive, e.g. `{{ param.img.src }}` or `{{ v1 }}`. Furthermore the following type error is thrown:

```
TypeError: scope.$new is not a function
```

I tried to compile with different scopes, e.g. `$scope` of the controller or simply `true` to generate a new scope, but none will evaluate the expressions within the directive template. I also tried to invoke `$scope.$apply()` after inserting the directive html into `someElement`, which didn't work either.

I'm kind of stuck at this point, out of ideas and thankful for any hints. I hope you guys can help me fix this.

Comment: try `$compile('...')($scope)`; You provide empty object instead of scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Using `$compile('<my-directive param="param"></my-directive>)($scope)` seems to bring me a little bit further. However it now seems like `param`, which is part of the method signuature `$scope.generateMyDirective = function(param){...}`, is not passed to the directive. This leads to errors when compiling the template, e.g. `Cannot read property 'img' of undefined`. How can I make sure the `param` passed to the method is in turn passed to the directive within `$compile()`?

Comment: My suspicion seems to be correct. If I bind `param` to `$scope` before calling `$compile()` in the controller it leads to every call to `generateMyDirective` showing the same `param`, but it won't throw errors. I, however, would prefer to avoid binding the method parameter to the controller scope and I need to be able to compile for different `param`s. Is there any other way of passing the parameter to `$compile` and therefore the directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with the help of @vp_rath and @pankajparkar!
The problem indeed lies with the `$scope`. In order to get the `param` passed to the call to `$compile()` we have two possible options. One solution is to bind `param` to the controller's scope and add a `$watch()`. The second way of doing this (and more what I was looking for) is: Instead of binding to the controller's `$scope` just create a new, vanilla scope like so:

```
// controller:
//
var generateMyDirection = function(param){
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.param = param;
    var compiled = $compile('<my-directive param="param"></my-directive>')(scope);
    someElement.innerHTML = compiled[0];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Very 1st thing where you made a mistake is you directive is incorrect. Camel case should be `-` separated with all the letter in small case

It should be

```
<my-directive param="param"></my-directive>
```

Instead of

```
<myDirective param="param"></myDirective>
```

Also `$compile` should compile element with a scope, you need not worry about the creating new `scope` from controller, your directive already has an isolated scope.

```
$compile('<my-directive param="param"></my-directive>')($scope);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My bad concerning the camel case to dash-separated notation, the actual directive has no camel case name, but a simple lowercase name, say `directive`, therefore resolving this issue.
Calling compile with the controller scope `$scope` results in the follwoing type error:

    `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

which I attribute to the custom filters used in the directive (which use some regular expressions to replace text). Do I need to inject the dependencies for the filters into the controller despite of them working naturally in html?

Comment: Changing to `replace: false` does not fix it. I suspect the `replace` in the error stemming from the calls to `text.replace(regEx)` in the filters. It seems like the `param` is not passed when calling `$compile`, leading to a call of `undefined.replace(regEx)` in turn leading to `Cannot read property replace of undefined`. But how do I make sure the `param` is passed properly when  compiling in the controller?

Comment: you need to put `$watch` on param inside your directive link.and do opearation on scope when it has value

Answer (score 0):

1. You should provide any scope to your directive compiler
2. all used variables (see `p` below) should be resolvable in the provided scope

---

```
$scope.p = {img: '', ...};  
$compile('<my-directive param="p"></my-directive>')($scope);
delete $scope.p;
```